# Can we register a .uk domain when we own the .co.uk but our registrar doesn't do .uk registrations?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar, country-specific

I currently have `.co.uk` with name.com who do not provide a `.uk` domain. Is there anyway I can register a `.uk` domain with a different provider for this domain?

Comment: You have to transfer the domain to a register who does offer uk reg

Comment: @mihai thats not correct

Comment: how is that? Last time I've checked they all asked me to transfer them the .co.uk domain.

Comment: See my answer...try names.co.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some registrars will allow you to register the .uk by verifying ownership of the .co.uk address.
For example, I registered the address [medexpress.co.uk](http://medexpress.co.uk) with name.com who do not offer .uk domains. I registered the [medexpress.uk](http://medexpress.uk) with names.co.uk, after supplying verification that I own [medexpress.co.uk](http://medexpress.co.uk).

However, some registrar's such as 123-reg would not allow me to register the .uk address without transferring the .co.uk address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can register it, just register the `.uk` at another registrar.

Comment: Not all registrars will let you do this. e.g. 123-reg will not register a .uk address if you do not have the .co.uk address with them.